# Receiving a stream of a NetGroup

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, p2p

I'm trying to receive a stream of a NetGroup (television) but it fails at some point. Here is the code (reduced to a testcase):

```
package lib
{
    import flash.events.NetStatusEvent;
    import flash.external.ExternalInterface;
    import flash.media.SoundTransform;
    import flash.media.Video;
    import flash.net.GroupSpecifier;
    import flash.net.NetConnection;
    import flash.net.NetGroup;
    import flash.net.NetStream;
    import flash.net.NetStreamPlayOptions;
    import mx.core.FlexGlobals;

    public class player
    {
        private var connection:NetConnection;
        private var group:NetGroup;
        private var group_option:GroupSpecifier;
        private var self:Object;
        private var stream:NetStream;
        private var stream_option:NetStreamPlayOptions;
        private var video:Video;

        private function _connect():void
        {
            self.connection = new NetConnection();
            self.connection.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, self._event_net_status);
            self.connection.connect('rtmfp://p2p.peer-stream.com');
        }

        private function _event_net_status(event:NetStatusEvent):void
        {
            if(event.info.code === '')
                return;
            ExternalInterface.call('echo', 'status', event.info.code, false);
            switch(event.info.code)
            {
                case 'NetConnection.Connect.Success':
                    self._p2p_start();
                    break;
                case 'NetGroup.Connect.Success':
                    self._stream_init();
                    break;
                case 'NetStream.Connect.Success':
                    self._stream_start();
                    break;
            }
        }

        private function _p2p_start():void
        {
            self.group_option = new GroupSpecifier('G:0101010c0b0e70726f2073696562656e00');
            self.group_option.ipMulticastMemberUpdatesEnabled = true;
            self.group_option.multicastEnabled = true;
            self.group_option.objectReplicationEnabled = true;
            self.group_option.postingEnabled = true;
            self.group_option.routingEnabled = true;
            self.group_option.serverChannelEnabled = true;
            self.group = new NetGroup(self.connection, self.group_option.groupspecWithAuthorizations());
            self.group.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, self._event_net_status);
        }

        private function _stream_init():void
        {
            self.stream = new NetStream(self.connection, self.group_option.groupspecWithAuthorizations());
            self.stream.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, self._event_net_status);
        }

        private function _stream_start():void
        {
            self.video.attachNetStream(self.stream);
            self.stream.soundTransform = new SoundTransform();
            self.stream_option = new NetStreamPlayOptions();
            self.stream_option.streamName = 'G:0101010c0b0e70726f2073696562656e00';
            self.stream.play2(self.stream_option);
        }

        public function player():void
        {
            super();
            FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.stage.quality = 'BEST';
            self = this;
            self.video = new Video(640, 480);
            FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.video_box.addChild(self.video);
            self.video.smoothing = true;
            self._connect();
        }
    }
}
```

The ExternalInterface call there shows me just the passed info in a textfield (I'm testing this in a browser). Here is the result of this output:

```
NetConnection.Connect.Success
NetGroup.Connect.Success
NetStream.Connect.Success
NetStream.Play.Reset
NetStream.Play.Start
```

But nothing happens on the player. Here are my thoughts:

- I'm using the same string as GroupSpecifier and streamName but I'm assuming this is wrong. If so how can I get the stream name of the NetGroup?
- I'm enabling everything from the GroupSpecifier as I don't know what are the minimum requirements to receive a stream and pass it then to another clients. Maybe enabling all makes some troubles here.

Maybe somebody can tell me how I can solve this problem to finally see a stream.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem: The streamName was indeed wrong and I could manually figure out the correct name. Also instead of using new GroupSpecifier() I must pass the known group-string directly to the NetGroup and NetStream object.